# Creating a remote GitHub repo using existing git Branches

Tags: git, github

I have a local git repo called `CoachingManager`. This has the following 3 `branches`:

```
master
new_model
auto_setup_account
```

How can I create a github repo called `CoachingManager` with the exact same branches? This should be trackable straight away.

Sorry new to the github so just wanted to understand if there is a quick and easy way of doing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a repo CoachingManager  in git hub and then you can migrate your repo using below command. https://github.com/user/CoachingManager.git is your github repo url.

```
git push --mirror https://github.com/user/CoachingManager.git
```